# VS Code: add return type annotations automatically in Python function definitions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, annotations

What I have:

```
def get_candy():
    return "candy"
```

What I want VS Code to automatically do:

```
def get_candy() -> str:
    return "candy"
```

When I later call `get_candy()` the annotation box automatically includes `-> str:` anyhow, but it would be nice if it was included in the source code as well.

The annotation extensions I checked do not do this either, the just add the `""" comments - ..."""` stuff.

Comment: What's the question?  Are you looking for information on how to write VSCode plugins, or looking for a recommendation on a plugin that does this?  (The latter would be considered off-topic.)

Comment: My assumption was that someone would know a one-line solution I will need to throw in one of the .json files or can at least point me at something relevant or similar. I don't expect that something this simple would require installing new extensions.

Comment: Parsing the code and inferring the static return type isn't a completely trivial thing.  If the extension you're using doesn't do it already, it's likely that it doesn't know how.

Comment: As I said, it *does* add it in the tooltip that pops up when I type `get_candy(`, it is just not added to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the return type of functions that don't explicitly show a return type, that is most likely pylance. While pylance does guess at return types, (1) it's not perfect, especially for complicated functions, and (2) I have never seen (nor can I find) anything about making it automatically add return types.

Assuming you *are* using pylance, you can always make a feature request on pylance's [issue repo](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues).